# How do I solve a nonlinear Least Squares Error problem using Tensorflow 2 in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

From known r, YC and ZC values I generate N (theta,YL) pairs using the equation:

```
YL = YC + ZC*tan(theta + r) + noise
```

Having N such (theta,YL) pairs I want to recover r, YC and ZC by minimizing an error function, SE, using TensorFlow 2.

The following Python code shows how I generate N such pairs and the error function:

```
import math
import random

YC = -0.25
ZC = 1.0
r = 4
N = 10

theta = []
YL = []

for theta_i in range(-10,11):
    YL_i = math.tan(math.radians(r + theta_i)) + YC
    noise = random.uniform(-0.001,0.001)
    YL_i = YL_i + noise
    print('theta: ' + str(theta_i) + ', YL: ' + str(YL_i))
    theta.append(theta_i)
    YL.append(YL_i)

def SE(r, YC, ZC, theta, YL):
    N = len(theta)
    E = 0
    for i in range(0,N):
        theta_i = theta[i]
        YL_i = YL[i]
        Ei = YC + ZC * math.tan(math.radians(r + theta_i)) - YL_i
        E = E + Ei**2
    return E


SE_0 = SE(4, YC, ZC, theta, YL)
print(SE_0)
```

How do I minimize SE using TensorFlow 2?